# Using Pandas to find section / window of least variance in time series

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, time-series

I have a time series dataframe of energy consumption.

How can I find the section or window of least variance? Let's say the size of the window is three, how can I get index 3,4,5?

| index | time | energy |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2021-04-21 16:00:00 | 14 |
| 1 | 2021-04-21 17:00:00 | 87 |
| 2 | 2021-04-21 18:00:00 | 3 |
| 3 | 2021-04-21 19:00:00 | 349 |
| 4 | 2021-04-21 20:00:00 | 355 |
| 5 | 2021-04-21 21:00:00 | 350 |
| 6 | 2021-04-21 22:00:00 | 21 |

I can do this by iterating through the rows, but there is probably a better Pandas way of doing this, right?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas This makes me think there is a better way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.rolling`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rolling.html) with [`Rolling.var`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.window.Rolling.var.html), then get index of minimal value by [`Series.idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmin.html) and last get 3 indices by `indexing`:

```
N = 3
idx = df['energy'].rolling(N).var().idxmin()

pos = df.index.get_loc(idx) + 1
out = df.index[pos - N:pos].tolist()
print (out)
[3, 4, 5]
```

If there is default index:

```
out = df.index[idx - N+1:idx+1].tolist()
print (out)
[3, 4, 5]
```